# What type of material should I use for a shelf over a washer and dryer?

Tags: woodworking

building a shelf to go over my washer dryer in our laundry room.  it will be 88" wide by 34" deep.  I've already mounted 2x4's on the walls across back and sides.

looking for advice on what material to use for the shelf?  considering melamine for the smooth finish or plywood.  can anyone recommend one or the other.  planning to put a support frame in the middle.

Comment: What are you planning on putting on the shelf? What is the distance between the washer/dryer and the shelf? And are you sure you want it 34" deep? That seems awfully deep to me for a shelf especially if it is above eye level.

Comment: Unless they're really building a counter. ... even still that might be a bit much.